# Changing a manifest file on a puppet master, how to get it to take hold

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I'm fairly new to Puppet and am using Puppet 3.x.  Right now I have a puppet master running locally, which I connect to using vagrant ssh.

At the moment if I change a manifest file on that puppet master I'm logging out of ssh and calling `vagrant destroy`, followed by `vagrant up`.

This takes a good 10 minutes.  Is there a faster/better way of doing this?  I'm looking at librarian-puppet but am not sure whether / how to use it in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Re-Run Provisioners

If you've already provisioned the machine at least once, you can make changes to your manifests and then run:

```
vagrant provision
```

on the host. This will re-run any provisioners without requiring a new Vagrant instance to be built and provisioned for the first time. In *most* cases, unless you have a pathological set of manifests, this will be significantly faster.